# How to submit a form using C in windows

Tags: html, c, windows, forms

I am trying to implement a simple web server in html form. It has to be in C language and for windows users.

```
/* FOR SERVER */
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
#include <windows.h>


short SocketCreate(void)
{
    short hSocket;
    printf("Create the socket\n");
    hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    return hSocket;
}
int BindCreatedSocket(int hSocket)
{
    int iRetval = -1;
    int ClientPort = 8888;
    struct sockaddr_in  remote = { 0 };
    /* Internet address family */
    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
    /* Any incoming interface */
    remote.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    remote.sin_port = htons(ClientPort); /* Local port */
    iRetval = bind(hSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, sizeof(remote));
    return iRetval;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    int socket_desc, sock, clientLen;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    char clienttan_gelen_message[200] = { 0 };
    char serverResponse[500] = { 0 };
    char response404[50] = { 0 };
    char serverResponseXmlData[] = "<body><h1>Simple Calculator</h1><br><name>Can</name><age>26</age></body>";
    char serverResponseXmlData2[] = "<form action = localhost:8888>"
    "<div><label>Multiplicand 1: <input name = \"m\" size = \"5\"></label></div>"
    "<div><label>Multiplicand 2: <input name = \"n\" size = \"5\"></label></div>"
    "<div><input type = \"submit\" value = \"Multiply!\">< / div>"
    "< / form>";
    char message[100] = { 0 };
    const char *pMessage = "hello";

    printf("Initialising winsock...\n");
    // The WSAStartup function is used to start or initialise winsock library. 
    // It takes 2 parameters ; the first one is the version we want to load and 
    // second one is a WSADATA structure which will hold additional information after winsock has been loaded.
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)  // wsa will hold additional info after winsock has been loaded.
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");



    //Create socket
    socket_desc = SocketCreate();
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");
    //Bind
    if (BindCreatedSocket(socket_desc) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed.");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("bind done\n");
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    //Accept and incoming connection
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");
        clientLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        //accept connection from an incoming client
        sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (int *)&clientLen);
        if (sock < 0)
        {
            perror("accept failed");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Connection accepted\n");
        memset(clienttan_gelen_message, '\0', sizeof clienttan_gelen_message);
        memset(message, '\0', sizeof message);
        //Receive a reply from the client
        if (recv(sock, clienttan_gelen_message, 200, 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("recv failed");
            break;
        }
        printf("Clienttan gelen mesaj: %s\n\n\n", clienttan_gelen_message);   

        // Send some data
        //sprintf(serverResponse, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n%s\r\n", serverResponseXmlData);
        sprintf(serverResponse, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n%s\r\n", serverResponseXmlData2);

        if (send(sock, serverResponse, strlen(serverResponse), 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("Send failed");
            sprintf(response404, "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n");
            send(sock, response404, strlen(response404), 0);
            return 1;
        }
        //closesocket(sock);
        Sleep(1000); // Note uppercase 'S'
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

I managed just to send a simple text to the browser but have no idea about how to send a form in order to fill it out in the browser side. My reasearch over the internet did not yield anything.

Can anybody help me how to solve this out??

Comment: What is not working? If you can send text to the browser, then just send text that is the html code for a form.

Answer (score 0):

To process a HTML form the server needs to process the form data submitted via the GET or POST method used.

But instead of starting from scratch you may want to consider a library that already implements all of this. This one works on Windows and has an LGPL license: http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/